# How do you stack two DIVs vertically alongside two other horizontal DIVs?

Tags: css, html

For example:

```
DIV 1    DIV 2    DIV 3

                  DIV 4
```

How would I code the last two DIVs?

Comment: This _is_ a real question - been iterating on many solutions - and not finding anything definitive.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the elements inside a container, so wrap the first 2 divs inside an element and float to left, and float the other wrapping element to the right.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/maDmh/) (Borders are for illustrative purposes)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/maDmh/1/) (Without borders)

```
<div class="left_wrap">
    <div class="left1"></div>
    <div class="left2"></div>
</div>
<div class="right_wrap">
    <div class="right1"></div>
    <div class="right2"></div>
</div>

.left_wrap {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px; 
    float: left;
}

.right_wrap {
    border: 1px solid #0f0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
}

.left1, .left2 {
    float: left;
    width: 49%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 40px;
}

.right1, .right2 {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 80px;
}
```

> Note: Don't forget to clear your floating elements

Answer (score 1):

try this

**css**

```
div{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    border:solid 1px #000;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.one{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.two{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.three{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.four{
    clear:both;
    margin-left:224px;
}
```

here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ks2MK/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to encapsulate them in a container.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/MN7Mp/11/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">

    </div>
    <div class="left">

    </div>
    <div class="right">
    <div class="other">

    </div>
    <div  class="other">

    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```